# Is there a way to extract numbers in between the parantheses?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which are addresses and is stored in test.
I was thinking of using str_subset to retrieve the numbers in the test.
The data sets are address such as

```
"Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111, 112, 113, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 132, 133, 134) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)"
```

I would like to know how to get just " 110", " 111", "112" ....... " 108" as an answer. I tried `grep` and `str_extract` and `str_subset`. I used  `gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', test)`:

```
 [1] "   11 ( 110, 111, 112, 113, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 132, 133, 134) /    12 ( 108)"
```

Someone please enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
mystr <- "Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111, 112, 113, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 132, 133, 134) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)"

stringr::str_extract_all(mystr, "[0-9]+(?=,|\\))")

# [[1]]
#  [1] "110" "111" "112" "113" "119" "120" "122" "124" "126" "127" "128" "129" "132" "133" "134" "108"
```

You could make it a little bit more stringent by using `stringr::str_extract_all(mystr, "[0-9]{3,}(?=,|\\))")` instead (presupposing all these numerical strings are *at least* 3 characters long).

`stringr::str_extract_all(mystr, "(?<=\\s)[0-9]{3,}")` also works well if the numerical string(s) will always be preceded by a (single) whitespace character.

### Edit:

Additional solution based on OP's comment. I am not entirely sure *what* OP has in mind, but this should pull every number within the `(Blk ...)` expression, and report it as its own line in the `nums` column of the resultant `data.frame`. If no matching numeric strings are found, the function returns a `NA` in the `nums` column.

```
#Libraries
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

#Function
getnums <- function(x){
  
  nums <- unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\(Blk\\s)([0-9,\\s]+)(?=\\))"))
  nums <- unlist(str_split(nums, ", "))
  
  if(is.null(nums)) { nums <- NA}
  df <- data.frame(str = x, nums = nums, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  return(df)
}


#Example run
mystr <- c("Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)", 
           "Eastwood Dr/ Eastwood Rd (Laguna 88) / Jln Greja")


df <- bind_rows(lapply(mystr, getnums))

df

#                                                          str nums
# 1 Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)  110
# 2 Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)  111
# 3 Pasir Ris St 11 (Blk 110, 111) / Pasir Ris St 12 (Blk 108)  108
# 4           Eastwood Dr/ Eastwood Rd (Laguna 88) / Jln Greja <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue with the first solution stringr::str_extract_all(mystr, "[0-9]+(?=,|\\))") got me  "88" when the input was "Eastwood Dr, Green, Pl, Rd, Ter, Walk, Way / Eastwood Rd (Fairmount Condo, Laguna 88) / Jln Greja" . I only wish to get numbers that are within the bracket and the bracket must contain the word "Blk"

Comment: @itdriger you should have mentioned that in the OP then. Anyway, see if the solution I've edited into my post works better. I am not sure what exactly it is you have in mind, and this was the most general approach I could think of.